# How to mock security context holder in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, junit4

We have below code snippet in our spring boot rest api to get the user role.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if(auth.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_roleName1"))){
// some conditions
} else if (auth.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_roleName2"))){
// some conditions
}
```

We have this in one of the test class.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
Authentication auth = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
}
```

But junit test case is failing. Please suggest how to write junit test case for security context holder (for above mentioned code).

Comment: If it really is a plain unit test it should work, you are probably writing an integration test using `MockMvc` for which you have to provide proper authentication information.

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate your test method with @WithMockUser (available since spring 4.0) e.g. `@WithMockUser(roles = "MANAGER")`

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "myuser", password = "pass", roles = "USER")
public void test() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/foo"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Remember to add the following dependency to test the dependencies of your project:

`org.springframework.security:spring-security-test`

Comment: We have annotated the class with AutoConfigureMockMvc and autowired MockMvc but getting NullPointerException : mockMvc is null.

Comment: maybe this could help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534247/spring-boot-mvc-test-mockmvc-is-always-null